# Screen and cursor freeze temporarily

Tags: freeze, cursor

I have a problem with cursor lagging.

- I tried reinstalling Linux and even changing distribution but I have still the same problem.
- I have it installed on a USB stick and this bug is only on kernel 5.19 and only on my computer.

Sometimes after I log in, a big black block appears for like 10 seconds and I can't do anything, I think its a driver problem but I dont know. 2 weeks earlier everything was fine.

Comment: Maybe you've identified a bug and you could file a bug report with the maintainer. But then you'll need to provide more details, in particular about your hardware since it seems to be affected by this bug. Since you gave few details overall I don't know what kind of help you are hoping for. My suggestion would be to downgrade your kernel in the meantime. The bug could very well be fixed later on. But reporting the issue can perhaps speed up resolution, especially if it affects very few people. If nobody bothers to do that, the bug could remain ignored for a long time.